# How to get real attr values in didReceiveAttrs hook, if it's a mutable cell

Tags: javascript, ember.js, mutable, lifecycle-hook

Please see below sample code.
Given I have a component `my-text-box`

`my-text-box.hbs`

```
{{my-text-box value=modelName}}
```

I want to observe the changes of `value` property via `didReceiveAttrs` hook instead of `observers` for better performance.

`my-text-box.js`

```
didReceiveAttrs: function(args) {
    if (args.oldAttrs == null) {
        // This is the initial render, but I don't need to anything here.
    } else if (args.newAttrs.value != args.oldAttrs.value) {
        // supposed `value` was changed from outside, I can do something here...

        // BUT, `args.newAttrs.value` is not always the prop value, 
        // `Ember` would automatically wrap it with `{{mut}}` helper. 
        // The data structure would be: 
        // {
        //    value: value,
        //    update: function (val) {
        //        source.setValue(val);
        //    }
        // }
    }
}
```

What I want is that I don't have to care whether the attr value is a `mutable` cell or not, I should get a way that always get the real value. I see there is a `HTMLBars hook` `ember-htmlbars/hooks/get-value` but it's not exposed to public API. And what I'm thinking is that maybe `Ember` should change both `newAttrs` and `oldAttrs` to have direct values instead of those `mutable` objects.

Does anybody have a way to handle that? Thanks!

Comment: `newAttrs` and `oldAttrs` aren't public API either :X

Comment: so it's hard to replace `observers`, I need to know whether one property is changed or not. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#event_didReceiveAttrs

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to store the previous value yourself, and then compare:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  _previousAttr: null,

  didReceiveAttrs() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    if (this.get('_previousAttr') !== this.get('attrName')) {
      this.set('_previousAttr', this.get('attrName'));
      // do your thing
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It makes sense to me, I'm doing like this too. But I have to make a `shadow` for all properties I need to watch, it's lot of extra works. Much better if Ember extracts the `new` values and `old` values, I can easily compare them, without any extra cost. Hope Ember maintainers can see this, and consider it.

Comment: Did you get any solution? I am having the same issue. Please help to resolve mine!

Answer (score 1):

Ember component lifecycle hook args are deprecated according to [RFC #191](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0191-deprecate-component-lifecycle-hook-args.md).

So it would be better to do thing like this:

```
Ember.Component.extend({
  didReceiveAttrs() {
    let oldAttrs = this.get('_previousAttrs');
    let newAttrs = this.get('newAttrs');

    if (oldAttrs && oldAttrs !== newAttrs) {
      this.map.move({ from: oldAttrs, to: newAttrs });
    }

    this.set('_previousAttrs', newAttrs);
  }
});
```

Or maybe you can use this [ember-diff-attrs addon](https://github.com/workmanw/ember-diff-attrs) for a while.